# How render template from current app in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have index.html in two places. One in /templates/index.html and another in /myapp/templates/index.html

In settings i have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    dict(BACKEND='django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', DIRS=[

        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates'),
    ], APP_DIRS=True, OPTIONS={
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ]
    }),
]
```

in /settings.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myapp/(?P<param>\w+)/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp',  app_name='myapp'), name='myapp'),
]
```

in myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

in myapp/views.py

```
def test(request, param):

    response = TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {})

    return response
```

How can I get explicitly index.html from current app, not from root templates folder? I tried with

```
response = TemplateResponse(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
```

but raise error : TemplateDoesNotExist

If I put os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') after os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'room/templates') , work fine. No other way to prioritize search the template in project, depending on the current application, namespace etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your templates in `templates/<app_name>/` or `<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/`. They will be automatically found by Django.

Django will look in the main templates folder `templates/<app_name>/` and after `<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/`.

And then in your view :

```python
response = TemplateResponse(request, '<app_name>/index.html', {})
```

Comment: Got to say, a 6 year answers help me today. Honestly, I usually never bother to use more than one app, so a simple `render(request, 'index.html')` suffice. But with more than one app, this answer will help you